# Can you explain the sentence for me? It's from Silverview by Le Carre

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I’ve heard about bumble bees that fly as shouldn’t. I’ve not heard about dead ones as can."

from Silverview by Le Carre:

> ‘They’ll do you in, and they’ll do me in,’ she predicted in her rich Lancashire growl. ‘That’s all the buggers care about: putting us honest traders out of business. Soon as they spot you earning half a living, they’ll open an industrial-sized book department, and won’t rest till you’re a charity shop. All right, let’s have it about your festival. I’ve heard about bumble bees that fly as shouldn’t. I’ve not heard about dead ones as can.’

Comment: _As_ is used in various dialects as a relativiser. Substitute _that_ for _as_ and see if it makes sense to you. It is referring to a famous legend that claimed that an eminent physicist had proved that bumble bees were unable to fly.

Answer (score 2):

"As" can be used instead of "that" to form a relative clause in some dialects (including Lancastrian):

> It’s father as calls me Sissy, sir.

In standard English  Dickens would have written "It's father that calls me Sissy, sir."

So the quote is about "bumblebees, that shouldn't (be able to fly)".  This refers to a common [urban myth that](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/bumblebees-cant-fly/) "according to science, bumblebees are too heavy to fly"

But the speaker has not heard of "dead bumblebees that can fly".  It's not clear how this connects to the rest of the paragraph. It might be a metaphor, or it might be related to something specific in the "festival".